# How to override a static parent's property from within child class

Tags: php, oop

Simplified demo code:

```
<?php

class ParentClass {
    protected static $property = 1;

    public static function getProperty() {
        return self::$property;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    protected static $property = 2;
}

echo ChildClass::getProperty(); // Returns 1. I expected it to return 2.

?>
```

In the above code I expect the value of `$property` to be overwritten within `ChildClass`, and so for `ChildClass::getProperty()` to return `2`, but this is not the result.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to achieve. What is the correct way to go about this, and why does the above code not behave as expected?

Comment: Ooh! I had a look around but didn't find this question. Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `static` instead of `self`:

```
<?php

class ParentClass {
    protected static $property = 1;

    public static function getProperty() {
        return static::$property;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    protected static $property = 2;
}

echo ChildClass::getProperty(); // Returns 2
```

`self` refers to the class in which you use the keyword.